# Python 3.4: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, function, variables, global

I'm making a basic game in python and I'm trying to recall a global variable in a different function.
This is the error message I get:

```
File "C:\ARENA\Arena.py", line 154, in <module>
    gamea()
  File "C:\ARENA\Arena.py", line 122, in gamea
    if age1 > age2():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm still new to Python so I'm not sure what's wrong. Here's the part of my code that I'm trying to fix

```
    #character Titles Player1
def char1Title():
    print ("Player 1")
    print()
    global  myName1
    myName1 = input("Whom might you be?")
    print()
    global age1
    age1 = input("What is your age?")

#2 player gameplay code
def gamea():
    attack = input('Enter to start BATTLE!!!!')
**#here's where I try to call "age1" again:**
    if age1 > age2():
        print(myName)
        print("WINS!!")
    elif age2 > age1():
        print(myName2)
        print("WINS!!")
```

Comment: I see you tried to edit your error into my answer. I have edited my answer to comply. Does my answer work for you now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a string, don't put parentheses around the end, otherwise python will think it is a function:

```
>>> string = "hello"
>>> string()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> string
'hello'
>>>
```

Here is your edited code:

```
    #character Titles Player1
def char1Title():
    print ("Player 1")
    print()
    global  myName1
    myName1 = input("Whom might you be?")
    print()
    global age1
    age1 = input("What is your age?")

#2 player gameplay code
def gamea():
    attack = input('Enter to start BATTLE!!!!')
    if age1 > age2:
        print(myName)
        print("WINS!!")
    elif age2 > age1:
        print(myName2)
        print("WINS!!")
```

Also, you don't call `age2` anywhere, so make sure you do.